# Top structure that accept custom property

Tags: python, properties, data-blocks

You can create custom property associated to a data type like this:

```
bpy.types.Objects.MyProperty = bpy.props.IntProperty ()
```

So now all objects have this interger property and it's entrered value is saved with the blendfile. Same thing with Scene , NodeTree , Nodes ... etc.

But where I can save a value available for the entire blendfile? Not associated to something can be added or removed from the blendfile by the user. A kind of top node in the datablock. I find a place but not really sure it's a good idea:

```
bpy.types.WindowManager.MyProperty = bpy.props.IntProperty ()
```

I can retrieve it to:

```
bpy.data.windowmanager ['WinMan'].MyProperty
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Think you'll find `WindowManager` properties aren't saved with the blend file.